# Hadamard finite part of an integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How does one take the 'Hadamard finite part' of an integral? I am following a paper and the result stated is that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}U_{B}^{-2}(Y)-U_{B}^{2}(Y)\,\textrm{d}Y=-2.7950.$$

The function $U_{B}(Y)$ is calculated numerically (in fact it's the classical Blasius flat plate boundary-layer velocity profile - http://jhuang79.weebly.com/uploads/7/2/1/5/7215285/4475122_orig.jpg from this image read 'df1' as $U_{B}$ and 'eta' as $Y$). I know that

$$U_{B}(0)=0,\quad U_{B}(\infty)=1,\quad U_{B}'(0)=0.3321,\quad U_{B}'(\infty)=0.$$

Plotting the function $F=U_{B}^{-2}-U_{B}^{2}$ against $Y$ one observes that $F(0)=\infty$ and $F(\infty)=0$ therefore the integral is undefined? How does taking the 'Hadamard finite part' return the above stated result?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Very confused here.

Comment: I don't think there's a genuine way to _numerically_ take "finite part" of an integral, because it need not be the case that the thing just doesn't converge "nicely", it might diverge wildly. "Finite part" makes best sense when there is a complex parameter in the integral, in which the integral admits a meromorphic continuation, and "taking finite part" amounts to subtracting the polar part(s) at the poles between the region of convergence and the desired point. This often leaves something convergent. But the dependence on the parameter has to be natural, ... or you can get any number at all.